# Adding JavaScript to page increases font of text

Tags: javascript, html

The issue is that when I`m adding some extra JavaScript to my page, the rest of the text on the page increases in font size.

Below is the example of a code I`m adding to my page.

```
<div id='ownedit'>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.ownedit.com/ownedit_js/ownedit.js?store_id=0866c14cd53fff56724c6fd35e72cd07&anchor=ownedit_banner'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>function post_to_owned_it()
    {
        var details ={"order_id":"112",
                    "customer_email":"me@me.com",
                    "order_currency":"USD",
                    "store_name":"LocalHost - Getshopped",
                    "order_value":"16.31",
                    "products":[{"product_name":"Eprocessing Declined",
                                    "product_url":"http:\/\/www.localhost.com:8080\/getshopped\/products-page\/product-category\/eprocessing-declined\/",
                                    "product_desc":"Eprocessing Declined",
                                    "product_price":"16.31",
                                    "currency":"USD",
                                    "product_id":"9",
                                    "product_quantity":"1",
                                    "product_image_url":"http:\/\/www.localhost.com:8080\/getshopped\/wp-content\/plugins\/wp-e-commerce\/wpsc-theme\/wpsc-images\/noimage.png"}
                                ]};
        post_it(details);
    }
    onLoadCallBack(post_to_owned_it);
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this particular script append a style sheet?  After some digging here is the stylesheet it is appending to your document https://www.ownedit.com/ownedit/analytics/css1.css but without seeing your html it is hard to said exactly which rule is at fault.  Though likely it is the rule they have placed on the body.

Comment: Sounds like owndit.js is being a bad citizen with your CSS. You may need `!important` directives in your own CSS font specs, even though that's not a great thing to have to do.

Comment: if i have to edit my code for this then i`m better off whitout it.

Comment: You could also make a small html page containing this code and add it in an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

owndit.js seems to have some code which manipulates your css